# Notification URL of Microsoft Graph Beta API return 406 Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Microsofts Graph API(Beta Version) to subscribe. But it gives me 400 Bad requests. As I debugged the issue I got an internal issue that NotificationUrl returns 406 not acceptable error.

I tested the same NotificationUrl from the Postman and it gives me 200 OK responses. Can you guys please help me to solve this issue?

I followed this doc to call the NotificationUrl
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Answer (score 0):

The 406 Not Acceptable is an HTTP response status code indicating that the client has requested a response using Accept- headers that the server is unable to fulfill. Make sure you are adding below header
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=utf-8